# How to add multiple filters to a chart using Mongodb Charts SDK

Tags: javascript, mongodb, filter, mongodb-charts

The MongoDB charts SDK allows you to filter a chart on whitelisted fields. In the dashboard itself, you can add more than one filter to a chart but as soon as you embed the chart using the Javascript SDK you can only use one filter. This is what the code looks like for a filter, is it possible to add another filter on 1 chart using clever javascript?

```
import 'regenerator-runtime/runtime';
import ChartsEmbedSDK from '@mongodb-js/charts-embed-dom';

const sdk = new ChartsEmbedSDK({
  baseUrl: 'https://charts.mongodb.com/charts-project-0-bhitm',
});

const chart = sdk.createChart({
  chartId: 'd1be814a-7ff2-4f3d-bd61-521589279fd9',
  background: 'transparent',
  height: '1200px',
  showAttribution: false,
});

async function renderChart() {
  await chart.render(document.getElementById('Box1'));

  document
    .getElementById('game-filter')
    .addEventListener('change', async (e) => {
      const game = e.target.value;
      const currentFilterDOM = document.getElementById('currentFilter');
      if (game) {
        await chart.setFilter({ _id: game });
        const filter = await chart.getFilter();
        currentFilterDOM.innerText = JSON.stringify(filter);
      } else {
        await chart.setFilter({});
        const filter = await chart.getFilter();
        currentFilterDOM.innerText = JSON.stringify(filter);
      }
    });
}

renderChart().catch((e) => window.alert(e.message));
```

any help will be appreciable thanks in advance

Comment: I cannot get chartFilter({}) to work at all. Did you have any success here? Can you post an answer?